# Searching files for different format

Tags: windows-search

Now i am using windows "Search result" for file search operation. It is working fine. I want to search some different format.
EX:

file name : FileTest1.xml, FileTest2.xml, FileTest3.xml... contains test folder.

I want to search what are the **file names contains "Test"**, those file have to list out means i searching like that --> *Test*.xml

I want to search what are the **file names not contains "Test"**, those files i have to list out.
how to search?

Answer (score 2):

default windows search got limitations. instead you could use [WinGrep](http://www.wingrep.com/). its a free tool for better searching and it supports variety of features including regex.. try this